# Python: date formatted with %x (locale) is not as expected

Tags: python, datetime, internationalization, locale

I have a datetime object, for which I want to create a date string according to the OS locale settings (as specified e.g. in Windows'7 region and language settings).

Following Python's [datetime formatting documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), I used the `%x` format code which is supposed to output "*Locale’s appropriate date representation.*". I expect this "representation" to be either Windows "short date" or "Long date" format, but it isn't either one.
(I have the short date format set to `d/MM/yyyy` and the long date format to `dddd d MMMM yyyy`, but the output is `dd/MM/yy`)

What's wrong here: the Python documentation, the Python implementation, or my expectation ?
(and how to fix?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After reading the [setlocale() documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html#locale.setlocale), I understood that the default OS locale is not used by Python as the default locale.  To use it, I had to start my module with:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
```

Alternatively, if you intend to only reset the locale's time settings, use just `LC_TIME` as it breaks many fewer things:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, '')
```

Surely there will be a valid reason for this, but at least this could have been mentioned as a remark in the Python documentation for the %x directive.

Comment: From https://wiki.debian.org/Locale: "Using LC_ALL is strongly discouraged as it overrides everything. Please use it only when testing and never set it in a startup file. "

Answer (score 5):

Is your locale set in your script? If you call `locale.getlocale()`, is the result expected? Compare below:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getlocale()
(None, None)
>>> import datetime
>>> today = datetime.date.today()
>>> today
datetime.date(2010, 8, 9)
>>> today.strftime('%x')
'08/09/10'
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "de_DE.UTF-8")
'de_DE.UTF-8'
>>> locale.getlocale()
('de_DE', 'UTF8')
>>> today.strftime('%x')
'09.08.2010'
```

Note that there are bugs in the `datetime` module, mostly because of bugs in the underlying C libraries. On my installation (latest OS X), for example, the formatting string `%z` is completely unavailable.

On Windows, the syntax of locale strings available to `setlocale()` follows a different syntax than on *nix platforms. A list is [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cdax410z.aspx).

And if you just wish to set your script to whatever default locale your users have installed (in mine: UK English), you just do this at the beginning of the main script. Don't do it in modules, as it overrides a global variable:

```
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "")
'en_GB.UTF-8'
```