# datetime change language from english to ukrainian python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime

```py
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%d.%B.%Y - %A - %X" ))
```

how can I add ukrainian language to this datetime?

Comment: and connect the package to the main program, in which the user selects the language in which he wants to get the value of the current date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: date formatted with %x (locale) is not as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438120/python-date-formatted-with-x-locale-is-not-as-expected)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Babel's date module](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/dates.html) (after pip installing it):

```
>>> from babel.dates import format_datetime
>>> import datetime
>>> format_datetime(datetime.datetime.today(), locale='uk_UA')
'8 квіт. 2019 р., 20:23:32'
```

Does this give you what you want?

You can also [use Babel's pattern syntax](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/dates.html#pattern-syntax) to format the date string, but I am not familiar with Ukrainian date formatting some I am not sure if this formatting is correct:

```
>>> format_datetime(datetime.datetime.today(), "d.MMMM.Y - EEEE", locale='uk_UA')
'8.квітня.2019 - понеділок'
```